# How to make Custom UIview which have rounded cornes, in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I want to make Custom UIview which have rounded cornes.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow

Comment: post are already available related to this question, it is not a new topic.

Comment: Do some research before asking a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you need to import Quartz framework. You can also set Bordercolor, shadow color, corner width, etc to that view.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And try this code.

```
        [self.YourView.layer setCornerRadius:1.0];
        [self.YourView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
        [self.YourView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [self.YourView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: Thnaks aloot... But 1 More question, how to set border color balck beacuase after changing color to blackcolor it will give only graycolor border?

Comment: Once Increase the Border width and check please

Answer (score 2):

**Add This Framwork**

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" 


UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake("As You Need")];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 15.f; // set as u need
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor; // set color as u need
    view.layer.borderWidth = 2.f; // set as u need
```

Answer (score 0):

First add QuartzCore Framework to your project.

Then import it into your class where you want to set your view corner radius,

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now make an IBOutlet in .h file to UIView (Assuming added by you in your XIB)

```
    IBOutlet UIView *backViewGroupName;
```

In your .m file,set sorner radius to your view

```
backViewGroupName.layer.cornerRadius=10.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the QuartzCore Framework

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then do this

```
View.layer.borderWidth = 3;
View.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
View.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Don't forget masks to bound = yes.