# iOS6 Add Shadow to A Container UIView With A Corner Radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, core-graphics

*How can an encompassing UIView have both a shadow and a corner radius at the same time?*

I have tried other solutions suggested on SO multiple times, but unfortunately they do not seem to work for iOS6 (or at least not for me)

So I thought I might post this, so that an iOS6 solution can be found.

I have a container `UIView` which contains two subviews

```
- a custom UIImageView
- a custom UIView
```

I would like the entire UIView to have a corner radius of 2.5, but I would also like the UIView to have a shadow. **However, so far, I get only 1 of these 2 desires, never both at the same time.**

Here is my code, I have different versions of it with my different attempts with SO solutions, but this is just one of my versions.

```
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1].CGColor; //0.1
    self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
```

^here **self** is the containing custom UIView with two subviews described above

Does anyone know of an iOS6 solution to this problem?

---

UPDATE

So, I do not need a border colour, so I was not adding that when I saw the solutions, but this time I added that, using the solution in the comment below, and it seems that the UIView is getting rounded, but I really want the combined UIImageView and UIView to get rounded.

So basically, the UIImageView is on top, and the UIView is on the bottom.

So how do I get only the top of the UIImageView to be rounded, and only the bottom of the UIView to be rounded.

Thanks.

**Note: shadows work as one whole object, but the corner radius is not working as one whole object?**

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow

Comment: Yes, none of the solutions from that page worked for me, unfortunately @jfuellert

Comment: @jfuellert See the update, any thoughts on this?

Comment: As @Marcin Kuptel stated in his answer, disabling masksToBounds will let you see the shadow because it won't be getting trimmed by the view's bounds (Shadow width doesn't add to the view's dimensions). I'd suggest trying his solution though.

Comment: @jfuellert I tried that, but rounded corners does not work with his solution (for my UIView at least), appreciate the help though

Comment: @jfuellert I figured it out, see my answer to see how I got it to work. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.layer.bounds cornerRadius:self.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;

UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
[self addSubview:container];

[container addSubview:self.someCustomUIView];
[container addSubview:self.someCustomImageView];

container.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5;
container.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

So basically:

1. I set the shadow of the main UIView.
2. I created a container subview which contains two other subviews
3. I set the corner radius of the container subview
4. Voila! It works!
5. I hope this works for other people who have multiple subviews in one UIView
6. I'd like to thank everyone for their help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change this line of code:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

to this one

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

If you set masksToBounds to YES, then you won't see anything that extends beyond the view's bounds, and this is the case with a shadow.

This code is from my current project (iOS 6) and it works fine. I can see both rounded corners and a shadow.

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;

UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: self.layer.bounds];
self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

Comment: The corners are not rounded with this approach (or at least not with my UIView for some reason) @MarcinKuptel

Comment: Even if you set shadowRadius ?

Comment: Yep, I appreciate the help though, I will keep trying, I am not sure what is wrong with my UIView, but it does not seem to work. I feel the problem is with the encompassing two subviews than the main UIView

Comment: see my answer to see what worked for me. I upvoted yours too, since I am sure it will work for other people viewing this post. :) @MarcinKuptel

Comment: I get the shadow but it appears OVER the target UIView?