# Can't click on UIButton after add a subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I'm using a method to add a shadow to my buttons. The problem is after that, I can't click in them. I add the userinteractionenabled property to YES, but still can't tap.

This is the code.

How can I resolve that? Am I missing something?

```
- (UIView*)putView:(UIView*)view insideShadowWithColor:(UIColor*)color andRadius:(CGFloat)shadowRadius andOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset andOpacity:(CGFloat)shadowOpacity
{
    CGRect shadowFrame; // Modify this if needed
    shadowFrame.size.width = 0.f;
    shadowFrame.size.height = 0.f;
    shadowFrame.origin.x = 0.f;
    shadowFrame.origin.y = 0.f;
    UIView * shadow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:shadowFrame];
    shadow.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // Modify this if needed
    shadow.layer.shadowColor = color.CGColor;
    shadow.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
    shadow.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
    shadow.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    shadow.clipsToBounds = NO;
    shadow.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
    [view.superview insertSubview:shadow belowSubview:view];
    [shadow addSubview:view];
    return shadow;
}
```

Comment: Your `shadow` frame is 0,0,0,0 unless you posted incorrect code...

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution

After the comments of the people, I did some changes. This is the final code

```
+ (void)putView:(UIView*)view insideShadowWithColor:(UIColor*)color andBlur:(CGFloat)shadowRadius andOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset andOpacity:(CGFloat)shadowOpacity
{
    CGRect shadowFrame = view.frame;
    UIView * shadow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:shadowFrame];
    shadow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shadow.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // Modify this if needed
    shadow.layer.shadowColor = color.CGColor;
    shadow.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
    shadow.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
    shadow.layer.cornerRadius = view.layer.cornerRadius;
    shadow.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    shadow.clipsToBounds = NO;
    shadow.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
    [view.superview insertSubview:shadow belowSubview:view];
}
```

With this, you can have a view with round corners and shadows at the same time. And, of course, the touch events enabled!

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense because you've put a `UIView` on top of the button, which means that you can't access that button.  You've set `UserInteractionEnabled` on the `UIView`, but that's useless because you haven't asked the UIView to respond to touch events.  In this instance, I would suggest adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to the UIView instead of trying to put a `UIView` on top of a button.

Comment: so, I need to add a gesture to the shadow view? My IBAction will be useless?

Comment: As you've built it currently, the IBAction is useless.  Think about it...in the view hierarchy, you've placed a UIView on top of a UIButton, so the user doesn't have access to the button that sits below the view.  One workaround you could try is to use sendSubViewToBack on the shadow view and make the UIButton background color transparent, that should have the desired effect as well.  The UIButton would be on top and the shadow view would be visible through it

Comment: I'm trying to add the line [shadow bringSubviewToFront:view]; but it doesn't work. Also, I added [shadow sendSubviewToBack:view], but doesn't worked. 

What is the best approach to move the subview?

Comment: You want to send the shadow view to the back of self.view so it would look like this: [self.view sendSubViewToBack:shadow];

Comment: I added [view sendSubviewToBack:shadow]; before the return, but still can't click the button

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect shadowFrame; // Modify this if needed
shadowFrame.size.width = 0.f;
shadowFrame.size.height = 0.f;
shadowFrame.origin.x = 0.f;
shadowFrame.origin.y = 0.f;
UIView * shadow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:shadowFrame];
```

In the above code you have a view with frame 0,0,0,0. So how can you tap it?

Comment: Ok, I get your point. I change this to this

CGRect shadowFrame; // Modify this if needed
    shadowFrame.size.width = view.frame.size.width;
    shadowFrame.size.height = view.frame.size.height;
    shadowFrame.origin.x = 0.f;
    shadowFrame.origin.y = 0.f;

and change the shadow view background to green to see where it is. Now it is in the top left corner. But If I change the origin, the other elements change their position. How can I resolve this?