# UIView with shadow, rounded corners and custom drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, swift, drawrect

I have to create a custom `UIView` that will have round corners, a border, a shadow and its `drawRect()` method is overridden to provide custom drawing code with which several straight lines are drawn into the view (I need to use a fast, lightweight approach here since many of these views may be rendered).

The problem I'm currently facing is that the shadow doesn't apply anymore to the round corners as soon as I override `drawRect()` in the view class (even without any custom code yet in it). See the attached image for the difference:

[image]

In the view controller I'm using the following code:

```
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true;

    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;

    view.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    view.clipsToBounds = false;
```

In the overridden `drawContext()` I would use something like:

```
    var context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor);
    // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0); //start at this point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20.0, 20.0); //draw to this point
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

But as said above, the shadow problem occurs even without this code added.

Is there any other/better way to draw lightweight elements onto a view other than this approach that is compatible with round corners and shadows? I don't want to add any unnecessary extra views or image contexts to the view since these need to be light and performant.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This is a tricky one. `UIView`'s `clipsToBounds` is necessary to get the rounded corners. But `CALayer`'s `masksToBounds` has to be `false` so the shadow is visible. Somehow, everything works if `drawRect` is not overridden, but actually it shouldn't.

The solution is to create a superview to provide the shadow (in the demonstration below this is the `shadowView`). You can test the following in Playground:

```
class MyView : UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextAddRect(c, CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80))
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c , UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
        CGContextStrokePath(c)
    }
}

let superview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))

let shadowView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100))
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 5

let view = MyView(frame: shadowView.bounds)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
view.clipsToBounds = true

shadowView.addSubview(view)
superview.addSubview(shadowView)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mundi! I guess I cannot get around using a second view for the shadow in any case. Thanks for explaining and code example!

Comment: Great Answer to deal with the conflict with clips to bounds and maskstobounds

Answer (score 48):

I wrote a small extension to UIView to manage both rounded corners AND drop shadow.
As the variables are @IBInspectable, everything can be set directly in the storyboard !

```
//
//  UIView extensions.swift
//
//  Created by Frédéric ADDA on 25/07/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Frédéric ADDA. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable var shadow: Bool {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity > 0.0
        }
        set {
            if newValue == true {
                self.addShadow()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue

            // Don't touch the masksToBound property if a shadow is needed in addition to the cornerRadius
            if shadow == false {
                self.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
        }
    }


    func addShadow(shadowColor: CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor,
               shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0),
               shadowOpacity: Float = 0.4,
               shadowRadius: CGFloat = 3.0) {
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks in the storyboard :
[image: storyboard]

The result :
[image]

There is one requirement : *DON'T touch either clipToBounds on the view (in code or in IB) or masksToBound on the layer.*

NB: one case in which it won't work : tableViews.
As UITableView automatically triggers `clipToBounds`under the hood, we can't have a drop shadow.

EDIT: as Claudia Fitero aptly noticed, you need to leave a small padding around the view to which you are adding a shadow, otherwise the shadow won't be visible. A 2px-padding is enough generally (depending on your shadow radius).

Comment: Extensions rule. This is a huge time saver. Thanks, Frederic!

Comment: It didn't work for me, look my post in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43958505/3052059

Answer (score 23):

Shadow is dropped from whatever is inside view's layer. When you disable clipping, entire layer rectangle gets filled with default `backgroundColor` so the shadow becomes rectangular too. Instead of clipping it with rounded mask just make layer's contents rounded, draw them yourself. And `layer`'s border is drawn around its bounds, so you need to draw it yourself too.

For example, in `backgroundColor` setter set actual background color to `clearColor` and use passed color in `drawRect` to draw a rounded rect with.

In example below I declare properties as `IBInspectable` and the whole class as `IBDesignable`, so everything can be set in storyboard. This way you can even use default Background selector to change your rounded rect color.

### Swift

```
@IBDesignable class RoundRectView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.5
    private var customBackgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    override var backgroundColor: UIColor?{
        didSet {
            customBackgroundColor = backgroundColor!
            super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
    }

    func setup() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        customBackgroundColor.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius ?? 0).fill()

        let borderRect = CGRectInset(bounds, borderWidth/2, borderWidth/2)
        let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: borderRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius - borderWidth/2)
        borderColor.setStroke()
        borderPath.lineWidth = borderWidth
        borderPath.stroke()

        // whatever else you need drawn
    }
}
```

### Swift 3

```
@IBDesignable class RoundedView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0
@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.black
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.5
private var customBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
override var backgroundColor: UIColor?{
    didSet {
        customBackgroundColor = backgroundColor!
        super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}

func setup() {
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    customBackgroundColor.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius ?? 0).fill()

    let borderRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: borderWidth/2, dy: borderWidth/2)
    let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: borderRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius - borderWidth/2)
    borderColor.setStroke()
    borderPath.lineWidth = borderWidth
    borderPath.stroke()

    // whatever else you need drawn
}
}
```

### Objective-C .h

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface RoundRectView : UIView
@property IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;
@property IBInspectable UIColor *borderColor;
@property IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;
@end
```

### Objective-C .m

```
@interface RoundRectView()
@property UIColor *customBackgroundColor;
@end

@implementation RoundRectView

-(void)setup{
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    [super setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor{
    self.customBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    super.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [self.customBackgroundColor setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:self.cornerRadius] fill];

    CGFloat borderInset = self.borderWidth/2;
    CGRect borderRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, borderInset, borderInset);
    UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:borderRect cornerRadius:self.cornerRadius - borderInset];
    [self.borderColor setStroke];
    borderPath.lineWidth = self.borderWidth;
    [borderPath stroke];

    // whatever else you need drawn
}

@end
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/864wN.png)

Comment: this is actually a more elegant solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Hodit Thanks you've saved my lot of times.Thank you :-)

Comment: @VaibhavLimbani glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 8):

Here's the swift3 version of [Hodit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275003/hodit) answer, I had to use it and found it over here and did general corrections for XCode 8. Works like charm!

```
@IBDesignable class RoundRectView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0
@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.black
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.5
private var customBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
override var backgroundColor: UIColor?{
    didSet {
        customBackgroundColor = backgroundColor!
        super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}

func setup() {
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    customBackgroundColor.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius ?? 0).fill()

    let borderRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: borderWidth/2, dy: borderWidth/2)
    let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: borderRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius - borderWidth/2)
    borderColor.setStroke()
    borderPath.lineWidth = borderWidth
    borderPath.stroke()

    // whatever else you need drawn
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does, just pull up a `UIView` in your `tableViewCell` and inherit its class from RoundRectView. I have not tried it, though it should work.

Answer (score 5):

I find the following link helpful to understand setting the dropshadow:

[How to add a shadow to a UIView](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-shadow-to-a-uiview)

To set the round corner for UIVIEW just set the `layer.cornerRadius` value in interface builder, Please check screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 3 Solution**

Adapted from Mundi's answer

```
class MyView : UIView {
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            c!.addRect(CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 80, height: 80))
            c!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            c!.strokePath()
        }
    }

let superview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

let shadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 5

let view = MyView(frame: shadowView.bounds)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
view.clipsToBounds = true

shadowView.addSubview(view)
superview.addSubview(shadowView)
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this extension to `UIView`:

```
Import UIKit

extension UIView {
    
    /// A property that accesses the backing layer's opacity.
    @IBInspectable
    open var opacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.opacity
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.opacity = value
        }
    }
    
    /// A property that accesses the backing layer's shadow
    @IBInspectable
    open var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            guard let v = layer.shadowColor else {
                return nil
            }
            
            return UIColor(cgColor: v)
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.shadowColor = value?.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    /// A property that accesses the backing layer's shadowOffset.
    @IBInspectable
    open var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.shadowOffset = value
        }
    }
    
    /// A property that accesses the backing layer's shadowOpacity.
    @IBInspectable
    open var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.shadowOpacity = value
        }
    }
    
    /// A property that accesses the backing layer's shadowRadius.
    @IBInspectable
    open var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.shadowRadius = value
        }
    }
    
    /// A property that accesses the backing layer's shadowPath.
    @IBInspectable
    open var shadowPath: CGPath? {
        get {
            return layer.shadowPath
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.shadowPath = value
        }
    }
    
    
    /// A property that accesses the layer.cornerRadius.
    @IBInspectable
    open var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.cornerRadius = value
        }
    }
    
    
    /// A property that accesses the layer.borderWith.
    @IBInspectable
    open var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.borderWidth = value
        }
    }
    
    /// A property that accesses the layer.borderColor property.
    @IBInspectable
    open var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            guard let bcolor = layer.borderColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: bcolor)
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.borderColor = value?.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3

I made an UIView extension and its basically the same idea suggested by Mundi:

```
extension UIView {

func addShadowView() {
    //Remove previous shadow views
    superview?.viewWithTag(119900)?.removeFromSuperview()

    //Create new shadow view with frame
    let shadowView = UIView(frame: frame)
    shadowView.tag = 119900
    shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
    shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false

    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    shadowView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    superview?.insertSubview(shadowView, belowSubview: self)
}}
```

Use:

```
class MyCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    containerView.addShadowView()
}}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: How about the corner Radius? When do you set that?

Comment: Not all the code is provided to be able to get the same result as above.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Just need to mention that conrerRaidus needs to set on the main view. The corner radius is not linked to the shadow.

Comment: when orientation  changes  , shadows are not changing !

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4.1. For making rounded corner of UIView I have created Extension of UIView as follow.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewOuter: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewInner: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewOuter.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        viewInner.roundCorners(15.0)
        viewOuter.addViewShadow()
    }
}
extension UIView {
    public func roundCorners(_ cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    public func addViewShadow() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: (.now() + 0.2)) {
            let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).cgPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.6, height: 2.6)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 8.0
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]    [image]

Comment: I think you miss understood the question. Question is not about how to add corner radius to a view but how to add a circular shadow to circular corner view. Update your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The solution seems much easier than the problem might suggest. I had this with one of my views and used the core part of @Hodit's answer to get it to work. This is all you need actually:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // make sure the background is set to a transparent color using IB or code
    // e.g.: self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

    // draw a rounded rect in the view
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:5.0] fill];

    // apply shadow if you haven't already
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0,3.0);
    self.layer.shadowRadius= 1.0;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1;

    // more code here

}
```

Note that this doesn't clip subviews. Anything positioned at 0,0 in the view will overlap the visible top left rounded corner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is work for me...

```
    yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 05

    yourView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: yourView.bounds).CGPath
    yourView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Comment: It works! Which is great since it's quite a small solution. In my case it looks a little small and rough though just outside the border.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift. What did work for me was adding:

```
    self.noteImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

So, the full code is:

```
    self.noteImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.noteImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.noteImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.noteImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    self.noteImage.layer.shadowRadius = 1

    self.noteImage.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: noteImage.bounds).CGPath
    self.noteImage.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Comment: Not sure about where you're setting the corner radius property of the view, since this is the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Frederic Adda's solution, don't forget to position the view that has shadow with a padding to the superview, where the shadow can be drawn. Otherwise the shadow will be clipped off.
I made this mistake in my custom cell, and thought the solution was wrong until I added a padding of 8px all around.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. If you have multiple type of views like UIView, UIControl, UITableView and so on, and don't want to make subclasses of each of them, or you want to add this effect with smallest changes to your code, then this might be what you are looking for.

**Objective-C.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (CornerAndShadow)

- (void)setCornerAndShadow;

@end
```

**Objective-C.m**

```
#import "UIView+CornerAndShadow.h"
#import <Masonry.h>

@implementation UIView (CornerAndShadow)

- (void)setCornerAndShadow {
    // constants
    CGFloat fCornerRadius = 9.f;

    // only work for views with superview
    if (self.superview == nil) {
        return;
    }

    // set corner
    self.layer.cornerRadius = fCornerRadius;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // create and configure shadowView
    UIView *shadowView = [UIView new];
    shadowView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor; // just to make shadow visible
    shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = fCornerRadius;
    shadowView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3.f);
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.f;

    // put shadowView into superview right below self
    [self.superview insertSubview:shadowView belowSubview:self];

    // set shadowView's frame equal to self
    [shadowView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self);
    }];
    // use this if you're not using autolayout, and can get real frame here
    // shadowView.frame = self.frame;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I would have just done everything in your custom draw method like below.

I usually will do this if I know I want to apply a drop shadow to my rounded view (which of course means I don't want to use `masksToBounds`)

You also don't have to add an extra "shadow view" to the hierarchy.

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedView: UIView {

@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    // You could use custom IBInspectable attributes
    // for the stroke and fill color.
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.orange.cgColor)
    // Add a clipping path to get the rounded look
    // you want.
    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()
    // Fill and stroke your background.
    let background = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    background.lineWidth = 2
    background.fill()
    background.stroke()
}

private func shadow() {
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowRadius = 5
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    shadow()
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this function for your all views.

```
    extension UIView{

    func radiusAndBorder(radius:CGFloat, color:UIColor = UIColor.clear) -> UIView{
        var rounfView:UIView = self
        rounfView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(radius)
        rounfView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        rounfView.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        rounfView.clipsToBounds = true
        return rounfView
    }
}
```