# Create a round image with UIGraphicsImageRenderer

Tags: swift, xcode, uigraphicscontext

I have this extension, which creates a square UIImage.

```
extension UIColor {
    func image(_ size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { rendererContext in
        self.setFill()
        rendererContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}
```

How can I return a  circled UIImage?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368739/how-to-draw-a-simple-rounded-rect-in-swift-rounded-corners

Answer (score 1):

Looking at CGContext methods there is a `fillEllipse(in:)`. So instead of `fill()` (which make it fill all the image), we retrieve the `cgContext` of the `rendererContext` and call `fillEllipse(in:)` on it.

```
func circleImage(_ size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) -> UIImage {
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image(actions: { rendererContext in
        self.setFill()
        rendererContext.cgContext.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    })
}
```

In Playground:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can not test it right now. But wouldnt this create a squared Image with round fill? I need a round UIImage, not just the color to be rounded

Comment: What do you need? A rounded square or a circle? This will create a colored circle if the size is a square and an elipse if it is a rectangle, with a transparent background.

Comment: Sorry. I need a circle. I will test your code, although I do now know where you make the UIImage circled here. I thought your code will produce a squared UIImage with a colored circle inside.

Comment: This produces a a circle with the rest being transparent. I added the render.