# How to add shadow to a view inside cell in tableview in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have created a `tableviewcell` in XIB and used it in `tableview` using registering the class. I am using `autolayout` here.

But the problem is when i loading the `tableview` in `viewcontroller` the shadow of the view inside the cell is not setting correctly. it exceeds its bounds as i shown in picture with red box. [image]

But when is scrolling the `tableview` then the shadow of the view is shown correctly as expected.

The code used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is shown below:

```
let layer = cell.cellContectView.layer
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: layer.bounds).CGPath
```

Please note: the blurred text is not an issue. Its hidden for security reason

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the code for the layer from the cellForRowAtIndexPath and put it in your cell class in:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    let layer = self.contentView.layer
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.shadowRadius = 5
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: layer.bounds).CGPath
}
```

Comment: I tried that.. but it makes the cell shadow always wrong as shown in the image.. It doesnt even change when scrolling

Comment: The grey view on bottom is another sub view?

Comment: Yes.. Its like cell content view has a view with labels and images and also as you asked the bottom view with started is added as subview in view with labels and images

Comment: In that case you need to give a corner radius to the view also to avoid this white corner outside the content view.

Comment: clipstobounds not available

Comment: You are right because it is a layer. You can check the following maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591389/uiview-with-shadow-rounded-corners-and-custom-drawrect

Answer (score 0):

Adding a shadow inside `UITableViewCell` using `QuartzCore` code - can decrease scroll performance dramatically.
Better to create shadow graphic asset and add it as `UIImageView`.