# iOS Button with round corners and a shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have searched and tried the various solutions but without success. What I would like is a button background with rounded corners and a shadow. I can make one or the other happen but not both at the same time. Any help would be very welcome.

```
viewDepositButton_.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
CAGradientLayer *viewLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
[viewLayer setColors:aloColors];
[viewLayer setFrame:viewDepositButton_.bounds];
[viewDepositButton_.layer insertSublayer:viewLayer atIndex:0];
viewDepositButton_.clipsToBounds = YES;

viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.46 green:0.46 blue:0.46 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowRadius = 8;
viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f);
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code ?

Comment: I'd call your methods maybe after you set your properties! [viewDepositButton_.layer insertSublayer:viewLayer atIndex:0];
        [viewDepositButton_ viewLayer];} should be called way later.

Comment: Please look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your code to work by the following and it looks fine. Make sure you call your methods in proper sequence.

```
        viewDepositButton_.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        viewDepositButton_.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.46 green:0.46 blue:0.46 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
        viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowRadius = 8;
        viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
        viewDepositButton_.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f);

        CAGradientLayer *viewLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        [viewLayer setColors:aloColors];
        [viewLayer setFrame:viewDepositButton_.bounds];
        [viewDepositButton_.layer insertSublayer:viewLayer atIndex:0];
        [viewDepositButton_ viewLayer];}
```

Comment: At first glance that works however if you look closely at the button the corners are not rounded and extend out of the border. For now I think I may have to give up on the gradient and just use a plain colour.

Comment: I have found a way to make it work. What I needed to do to your code above was remove the border as I didn't want that and then add [viewLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f]; when defining the gradient layer.

Answer (score 5):

`viewDepositButton_.clipsToBounds = YES;` or `viewDepositButton_.layer.masksToBounds = YES;` will clip everything outside your layer - **including** the shadow.

However you have few options:

1. Put your button under a parent view, which will have the same corner radius and the shadow you want, but will have `clipsToBounds = NO`. This way you'll have your button as a subview of a view which has the shadow.
2. Use an image for your button, which has the rounded corners and set your buttons `clipsToBounds` to `NO`

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code for setting up a rounded corner button with shadow.

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
button.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1.0f, 3.0f);
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
button.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Overall, the code is pretty straightforward. Please comment if you have any question, concerns or bugs.