# The shadow not appear in collectionViewcell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I create a `collectionView` and I want to add shadow to every cell, I wrote this code

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        return cell
    }
```

but this is the output

[image]

I want it be like this
[UIView with rounded corners and drop shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow/34984063#34984063)

Comment: Does it help if you say `cell.layer.masksToBounds = false`?

Comment: @matt its work!! thank you

Comment: That's great, I'll give it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code will probably work if you also say:

```
cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

The reason is that a shadow is outside the layer's bounds, so if we are masking to the bounds, you won't see the shadow.

Comment: Slightly simpler: `cell.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Why is it wrong? Doesn't `cell.clipsToBounds` do `cell.layer.masksToBounds` ?

Comment: @leslie-godwin it’s wrong because true is not false