# add Shadow on UIView using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

prior swift 3 i was adding shadow in my UIView like this :

```
//toolbar is an UIToolbar (UIView)
toolbar.layer.masksToBounds = false
toolbar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
toolbar.layer.shadowRadius = 1
toolbar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

but the above code is not working in swift 3 , instead of shadow my whole View's color is turned to ugly gray

anyone knows how can we add shadow in swift 3 ?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
extension UIView {

  // OUTPUT 1
  func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    layer.shadowRadius = 1

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
  }

  // OUTPUT 2
  func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowOffset = offSet
    layer.shadowRadius = radius

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
  }
}
```

> **NOTE**: If you don't pass *any* parameter to that function, then the scale argument will be true by default. You can define a default value for any parameter in a function by assigning a value to the parameter after that parameter’s type. If a default value is defined, you can omit that parameter when calling the function.

**OUTPUT 1:**

```
shadowView.dropShadow()
```

[image]

**OUTPUT 2:**

```
shadowView.dropShadow(color: .red, opacity: 1, offSet: CGSize(width: -1, height: 1), radius: 3, scale: true)
```

[image]

> `layer.shouldRasterize = true` will make the shadow static and cause a shadow for the initial state of the `UIView`. So I would recommend not to use `layer.shouldRasterize = true` in dynamic layouts like view inside a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: if i want to remove this shadow, how m i supposed to do that?

Comment: @SuhasPatil  
if you want to remove the shadow then, why you adding it in the first place? Can you please elaborate your scenario so that I can give you a solution?

Comment: Actually for cell selection there will be shadow and deselection no shadow

Comment: @SuhasPatil if you want the shadow to be removed just change the `shadowOpacity` to 0

Comment: Why are we rasterizing here?  Created pixelation on the image in my view that used the shadow.

Comment: I would modify offSet to two variables: offsetX and offsetY. That way you don't have to input those two values as "width" and "height" (which sounds a bit wrong)

Comment: @SuhasPatil how did ur remove the shadow?

Comment: @iosMentalisti have removed all the sublayers as sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

Comment: Something here make the shadow get a static size, so this not good for different devices

Comment: `layer.shouldRasterize = true` make it static size, if you are using shadow for dynamic content like `UITableViewCell` etc, then you should not rasterize it. as the question here is simple: to add shadow to a `UIView`, not a resizing `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Worked for me in Swift 4.2, if you want to add shadow then do this : 
viewLoginCustom.dropShadow(color: yourColor, opacity: 1, offSet: CGSize.zero, radius: 3, scale: true)

Comment: If this isn't working you might need to run the function in 'override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()'

Comment: It is not worked. Swift 5, I just create a small project to add this shadow on an UIImage.

Answer (score 59):

**Shadow using UIView Extension Swift 4**

I would like to add one more line with selected answer!
When we rasterizing the layer, It needs to be set to 2.0 for retina displays. Otherwise label text or images on that view will be blurry. So we need to add `rasterizationScale` also.

```
  extension UIView {

    func dropShadow() {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        layer.shadowRadius = 1
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

Comment: All those `self.` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 53):

**Very simple and few lines of code:**

```
let viewShadow = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
viewShadow.center = self.view.center
viewShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
viewShadow.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
viewShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
viewShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
viewShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 5
self.view.addSubview(viewShadow)
```

Look like :
[image]

Comment: How can this work without setting masksToBounds to false

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal maskToBounds defaults to false.

Answer (score 22):

**This works for me (Swift 3 and 4)**

```
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
```

Comment: Thanks! If you change the third line as below. Shadow is more visible for people who tries for the first time.
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)

Comment: How can this work without setting masksToBounds to false

Answer (score 11):

Very easy to use extension for UIView, editable directly from storyboard. Swift 4+

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor?{
        set {
            guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
            layer.shadowColor = uiColor.cgColor
        }
        get{
            guard let color = layer.shadowColor else { return nil }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float{
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
        get{
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize{
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
        get{
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat{
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
        get{
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Although the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40720122/611879) is great and it works as it should, I've modified it to split `offSet: CGSize` to `offsetX: CGFloat` and `offsetY: CGFloat`.

```
extension UIView {
  func dropShadow(offsetX: CGFloat, offsetY: CGFloat, color: UIColor, opacity: Float, radius: CGFloat, scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: offsetX, height: offsetY)
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowRadius = radius
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5
Just call this function and pass your view

```
public func setViewSettingWithBgShade(view: UIView)
{
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    
    //MARK:- Shade a view
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please Try this

```
func applyShadowOnView(_ view: UIView) {
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    view.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this, it's working for me.

```
extension UIView {

    func dropShadow() {
    
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        layer.shadowRadius = 3
        //layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need rounded shadow. Works for swift 4.2

```
extension UIView {

        func dropShadow() {

            var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!
            let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 16.0
            let fillColor: UIColor = .white

            if shadowLayer == nil {
                shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()

                shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
                shadowLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor

                shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
                shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -2.0, height: 2.0)
                shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
                shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2

                layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

[Swift 4 rounded UIView with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRfFs.png)

Answer (score 3):

We can apply drop shadow by following way also

```
    cell.view1.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.view1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.view1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    cell.view1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Result will be : http://prntscr.com/nhhv2s

Comment: you made my day. Putting the backgroundColor did the trick :)

Comment: great then please do upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

For swift 5 users can do this way.

```
extension UIView {
  func addShadow() {
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
    func shadow(Vw : UIView)
    {
        Vw.layer.masksToBounds = false
        Vw.layer.shadowColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.5058823529, green: 0.5333333333, blue: 0.6117647059, alpha: 1)
        Vw.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        Vw.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        Vw.layer.shadowOpacity = 15.0
        Vw.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
loginView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use below the library because it allows you to set default values in one file and you can use it everywhere in the project without making one line of change.
https://github.com/Shahbaz89khan/ShadowView

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
toolbar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.hex(hexColor: "#000000", withAlpha: 1.0).cgColor
toolbar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
toolbar.layer.shadowRadius = 1
toolbar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
toolbar.layer.shouldRasterize = true
toolbar.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as a IBInspectable property for your views you can add this extension

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    private static var _addShadow:Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var addShadow:Bool {
        get {
            return UIView._addShadow
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if(newValue == true){
                layer.masksToBounds = false
                layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                layer.shadowOpacity = 0.075
                layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -3)
                layer.shadowRadius = 1

                layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
                layer.shouldRasterize = true
                layer.rasterizationScale =  UIScreen.main.scale
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spent lot of hours, I just find out the solution, just add this simple line.

backgroundColor = .white

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

**iOS shadow**

[[Advanced example]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73671786/4770877)

You are able to setup shadow using `layer`

```
view1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.magenta.cgColor

view1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
view1.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
view1.layer.shadowRadius = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

### Applies shadow over the View

---

```
func applyShadowOnView(_ view:UIView) {

        view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 5

}
```

Comment: How can this work without setting masksToBounds to false