# UIView with shadow and masked layer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, shadow

So I have an UIView (called **myView**) with some mask applied to it.

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 12, height: 12))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = myView.bounds
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
myView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Which layout this way:

[image]

What I am failing to do is add some shadow to **myView**. Since the view's layer have a mask, I am not able to add differents layers to it with shadow.

Does anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624675/add-shadow-on-uiview-using-swift-3

Answer (score 3):

set your image color to clear and to the following:

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: redView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 12, height: 12))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // your color
        maskLayer.frame = redView.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

        redView.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)

        redView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        redView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        redView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
```

Comment: Hey Denys! Adding the `maskLayer` as a sublayer is not rounding the corners. Your code is layouting my view like this: https://imgur.com/a/1ygV1

Comment: did you set UIVeiw background color to clear? this the effect: https://imgur.com/gallery/a2Xbx