# How to wrap UICollectionView section and items with a border (shadow)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I want to make a border/shadow around each pair of section and items of my uicollectionview.

Further I want to round the top corners of the section view and the bottom corners of the items in the last row.

Do you know how to do this? - Is it necessary to write a custom UICollectionViewLayout?

Comment: Please add relevant code done by you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add borders & rounded corners

```
cellName.layer.cornerRadius = cellName.frame.width / 2
cellName.layer.borderWidth = 5
cellName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black
```

and I guess 
[add Shadow on UIView using swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624675/add-shadow-on-uiview-using-swift-3)
will help you with the shadows also add shadows to the `contentView` of the cell

Comment: I think he his talking about sections, not cells