# Add shadow to button and uiview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uibutton, shadow

Add shadow to UIButton and UIView with the following parameters. I am able to set Opacity, Size, Distance but its not coming perfect. Can any one suggest how to add these. I have tried other solutions available on net but nothings works.

Angle: 90, 
Opacity 13%
Distance 4px
Spread: 10%
Size: 9px

[image]

This is the kind of shadow I am getting when I try to apply the following code.

```
self.buttonCategory2.setShadowWithColor(color: UIColor.black, opacity: 0.13, offset: CGSize(width: 9, height: 9), radius: 4, viewCornerRadius: nil)

extension UIView {

/**
 Set a shadow on a UIView.
 - parameters:
 - color: Shadow color, defaults to black
 - opacity: Shadow opacity, defaults to 1.0
 - offset: Shadow offset, defaults to zero
 - radius: Shadow radius, defaults to 0
 - viewCornerRadius: If the UIView has a corner radius this must be set to match
 */
func setShadowWithColor(color: UIColor?, opacity: Float?, offset: CGSize?, radius: CGFloat, viewCornerRadius: CGFloat?) {
    //layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: viewCornerRadius ?? 0.0).CGPath
    layer.shadowColor = color?.cgColor ?? UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity ?? 1.0
    layer.shadowOffset = offset ?? CGSize.zero
    layer.shadowRadius = radius
}
}
```

[image]

Required Shadow

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add Shadow on UIView using swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624675/add-shadow-on-uiview-using-swift-3)

Comment: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/07/18/swift-interface-builder/

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I am confused on how to set angle, distance and in which field they need to be added.

Comment: Your question is unclear you need to add more detail, a visual of what you want to achieve and what's your current output is along with code.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry Please check, I have updated my question.

Comment: and what type of shadow do you want according to photoshop ? they are just values, not the final look. Please add that too

Comment: @SaadChaudhry Please check

Comment: @NupurGupta Shunhank Gupta is my mentor :), please add more details to make us understand. So far I am unable to understand what the desired output should be.

Comment: see this link for the material design base shadow : https://medium.com/material-design-for-ios/part-1-elevation-e48ff795c693

Comment: @Shubhank I want to know where should I set distance, Spread, Size etc. Like, distance is shadowRadius , size is shadowOffset, spread is ???.

Comment: The iOS sdk does not allow setting spread and distance individually, you need to fine control using shadowRadius and offset only.

Comment: @Shubhank thanku so much