# How to do colour shading in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I need to do a colour shading in objective c. As shown in this image shade is on the button of HardService and SoftService.

Is there is any way to do this ? Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Comment: You can use either a gradient image or CAGradientLayer for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

CAGradientLayer would server your purpose - Reference:

http://blog.apoorvmote.com/gradient-background-uiview-ios-swift/

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a gradient image or CAGradientLayer for this purpose

`CAGradientLayer` added to an existing button:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = button.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
[button.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image for showing shadow. Use blur image or change alpha of the imageview.

Or if you want to do it programmatically, try it:

Obj c:

```
//create elliptical shadow for button through UIBezierPath
CGRect ovalRect = button.bounds;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:ovalRect];

 //applying shadow to path
 button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor yourcolor].CGColor;
 button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
 button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
 button.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
 button.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```

Swift :

```
//create elliptical shdow forimage through UIBezierPath
var ovalRect = button.bounds
var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: ovalRect)

//applying shadow to path
button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
 button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
button.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
button.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath
```

Taken from http://www.innofied.com/implementing-shadow-ios/ and also have a look to know more: [UIView with rounded corners and drop shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow)

My another answer related to this: [Drop shadow in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155443/drop-shadow-in-ios/40155658#40155658)

Comment: What is kShadowColor hear?

Comment: I want Shading on button not shadow for Button.