# How to add corner radius and shadow to a UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

[image]After **autolayout (Constraints)** How to make corner radius and shadow of the view **( even the view have some subview also )** and which method to write the code. If i write the code in **viewdidload , viewDidAppear** that i cant get the exact corner radius and shadow ?

This is my code which I do in viewWillLayoutSubview , I can get the corner radius but I cannot get shadow effects. If I remove view.layer.masksToBounds = true I can get shadow but its not corner only for base view not for its subviews ..

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.layer.masksToBounds = true

view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
view.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIView with rounded corners and drop shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow)

Comment: To achieve this I took two views one which will hold all subviews and another just an empty view of same constraints as of first view. Give corner radius to the view where all the subviews are there and give shadow to dummy view.

Answer (score 9):

```
    viewShadow.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    viewShadow.layer.masksToBounds = true;

    viewShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    viewShadow.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    viewShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    viewShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    viewShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    viewShadow.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

[image]

Comment: perfect solution brother!!!! I wonder it worked

Answer (score 3):

It depends on certain condition

1. If you set autolayout constrains from storyboard and size(height ,width)      of view is fixed then you can set corner radius in viewDidLoad.
2. If you set autolayout constrains from storyboard and size(height ,width)      of view is in ratio , so safe place for setting corner radius is viewWillLayoutSubview.
3. If you set constraints programmatically then there also can be certain conditions.viewWillAppear,viewDidAppear,viewWillLayoutSubview,viewDidLayoutSubview all can be handy depending on your situation.

Comment: try  setting layer.masksToBounds = false

Comment: If layer.masksToBounds = false then , I can get corner radius only for the base view, its subview are not getting cornerRadius.

Comment: I think you are required to set corner radius for each view

Comment: But its not looks goods when i do corner radius for all the views

Comment: Is that any other alternative option to do that without set corner radius for each view ?

Comment: I don't think its possible but you are free to check if it can be done so ,as google is our friend.But you can solve it by doing so let subviews = yourView.subviews;
for currentView in subviews {
    currentView.setRadius;
}  you can loop through all subview and set radius

Comment: But this will clip all the subviews inside that view, even view s which is in middle. I think he is not expecting to do that.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta can you explain why this will clip all subviews.

Comment: @Vikky because you are setting corner radius for every subviews.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta I don't think so. I have been using this approach all the time without any problem.Or may be i am unable to get your actual point what you are saying.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta I don't understand how subviews can be clipped unless you are using clipToBounds and i am pretty sure here we are not using that.

Comment: I mean not clipping but corner radius

Answer (score 3):

Add parentiew, parentView->View

set shadow and cornerRadius for parentView, maskToBounds = false

set cornerRadius for View, maskToBounds = true

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to set

```
layer.masksToBounds = true
```

and get shadow because maskToBounds will clip everything which falls in bounds of the view. And since shadow is put on bounds so it clips that also. Only way is to keep all the subview away from bounds.

One more way is that .

Add your view as a subview of another view, lets call it parent view.
 Add shadow to parent view with

```
 layer.cornerRadius = 10
 layer.masksToBounds = false
```

In your view add

```
 layer.cornerRadius = 10
 layermasksToBounds = true
```

This will work.

Comment: Then how to set the corner radius of the view (Including subviews) and shadow of the view ?

Comment: No its not Work for me

Comment: Can you share the design you want to achieve.

Comment: The above design i need a corner radius and shadow for the parentview

Comment: Keep your parent view as a subview of another base view. set shadow in base view with  layer.cornerRadius = 10
 layer.masksToBounds = false. Set your parent view without shadow with  layer.cornerRadius = 10
 layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: have you got it what I told.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code then after check in attribute inspector in storyboard it's shows you to set border color,shadow,radius.

```
extension UIView {

@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}

   @IBInspectable
   var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
       set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
       }
     }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
   var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
            layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            layer.masksToBounds = false
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Image look like below:[image]

Comment: @DanielKuta can you please describe little bit more.Thanks

Comment: Should the last line be:            `layer.shadowRadius = newValue` ?

Answer (score 1):

To add corner radius and shadow at the same time, you need to fake this view by adding another view of the same size, or rather subview on it.

So first, Add your view, Let's say that containerView it's like your parent view/superview that we will add shadow normally to it by:

```
containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
// or if you'd like to add shadow color in black, it's what you prefer
//containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
// shadow radius is optional, you can add or comment it
containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
containerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

then you can create subview on the `containerView` by:

```
containerView.addSubview(subContainerView)
subContainerView.backgroundColor = .white
subContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
subContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The `containerView` will reflect the shadow to the `subContainerView` which is really corner radius.

Note: If you'd like to change the background color of the view, Change the `subContainerView` background.

[Check this simple project](https://github.com/ahmedelserafy7/ShadowWithCornerRadiusViewSolution)

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer:

```
UIView * paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 320, 430)];
[paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

paintView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
paintView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
paintView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-.2f, .2f);
paintView.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
paintView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
paintView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:paintView.bounds];
paintView.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
[self.view addSubview:paintView];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this :

```
func addShadow(container : UIView){

    container.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    container.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    container.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    container.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    container.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution