# Making Circle Button with drop shadow not working correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am going to crazy because of this problem. I spent whole day with googling to solve this problem. But not find solution yet.

This is my problem.

```
scanBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "search-1"), for: .normal)
scanBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 171, green: 178, blue: 186, alpha: 1.0)
// Shadow and Radius
scanBtn.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
scanBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0.0, height:2.0)
scanBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
scanBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
scanBtn.layer.masksToBounds = false
scanBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 35.0
```

I set image to my button and set shadow and corner radius.
But conerRadius  is not working.
If I add clipToBounds = True, cornerRadius working but no shadow.
If I don't set image, conerRadius and shadow works well.

Please help me.

Comment: check for the `buttonType`, should be `.custom`

Comment: Thanks for your interests.

Comment: Button type is "custom". Problem occurs because of Image. Without image, cornerRadius and shadow works well.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984063/3151675) addresses the issue pretty well.

Comment: @the4kman Thank you very much.