# UIView Custom Class trigger either shadow or roundCorners/addCornerRadius but not both in swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uiview, swift4

UIView Custom Class trigger only shadow. I want to display both shadow and rounded corner for specific edges.Here is my code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    extension UIView {
        func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
    class CustomView: UIView {
     override func layoutSubviews() {
            self.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray
            self.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
            self.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            self.shadowRadius = 6.0
            //only rounded corners triggered in UI
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 15.0)
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: round corner requires clipToBounds property true while shadow requires clipToBound property false.

Comment: use two views one to give shadow and other for cornerRadius. test to write them above or below one another methods.

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow

Comment: @MRizwan33 Then how can i achieve this? can you tell me>

Comment: answer given below you can get idea. if it is correct than accept it otherwise commit below.

Comment: @MRizwan33 Then how can i achieve this? can you tell me? i already have UIButton within UIView but UIButton throws error for shadow and does not trigger    backButton.roundCorners([.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 15.0)     this method

Comment: in your above code there is no button used. share your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate views for the shadow and the border. The base view is transparent and has the shadow. The border view clips any other subcontent that it has to its borders. See the code below.

// add the shadow to the base view

```
baseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
baseView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
baseView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
baseView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
baseView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
```

// add the border to subview

```
let borderView = UIView()
borderView.frame = baseView.bounds
borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
borderView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
borderView.layer.masksToBounds = true
baseView.addSubview(borderView)
```

// add any other subcontent that you want clipped

```
let otherSubContent = UIImageView()
otherSubContent.image = UIImage(named: "lion")
otherSubContent.frame = borderView.bounds
borderView.addSubview(otherSubContent)
```

Comment: i want only two corners with round edges. Not for all corners.

Comment: this is another question ask it as another question. i answer as you asked. do not extend your question.

Comment: please read the title i mentioned roundCorners/addCornerRadius those are two types of method that perform for specific corner with round edge.

Comment: roundCorner/addCornerRadius are these builtin methods?

Comment: again the same take two views one for shadow other for cornerRadius. get idea from my code.

Comment: i tried only shadow triggered. Thats why i raise question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167732/discussion-between-mrizwan33-and-yazh).

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:-

```
func addShadow(view: UIView, corner: CGFloat) {
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = corner
}
```