# How to set UIView mask with corner radius, border and shadow?

Tags: ios, swift

what I'm trying to achieve is to apply a mask to `UIView` together with `shadow`, `border` and `cornerRadius`.

By now I'm able to set `mask`, `cornerRadius` and `border`. Issue is with trying to set `shadow`.

This is my code so far

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.cgPath
layer.mask = mask

let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
frameLayer.path = path.cgPath
frameLayer.lineWidth = width
frameLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
frameLayer.fillColor = nil

layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
```

Issue is if I try to set `shadow` to frameLayer or layer, I'm not getting desired results. It gets clipped by mask. Is there any way to achieve this except to use next lines of code?

```
layer.cornerRadius = 5
layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
layer.borderWidth = width
layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
layer.shadowRadius = radius
layer.shadowOffset = offset
clipsToBounds = true
```

Both snippets are intended to be used inside `UIView` subclass, so if anyone can help me regarding this I would really appreciate it. Thanks

If there is something else needed or something unclear please let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow ?

Comment: @Larme this is not the answer that I need, I'm asking about mask layer, shadows, border and corner radius. . Please read the question

Comment: can you add your full code for your custom `UIView`? @Baki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, just half hour later I managed to find solution to my own problem:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
frameLayer.path = path.cgPath
frameLayer.shadowPath = path.cgPath

frameLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
frameLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
frameLayer.fillColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
frameLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
frameLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
frameLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
frameLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor

layer.mask = frameLayer
layer.insertSublayer(frameLayer, at: 0)
```