# Shadow on UIVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow

I'm trying to accomplish a shadow similar to this one [image]

The code I try to accomplish the above with is the following, but it doesn't quite nail it.

```
mainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
mainView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
mainView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
mainView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Any idea how to replicate the exact shadow of the image?

Comment: How should one measure nailed-it-ness?

Comment: By replicating the shadow on the image.

Comment: You could provide an image of what your code generates, it's kinda hard to guess which values you have to tweak without any reference.

Comment: You may find a way to nail it in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984063

Answer (score 0):

Increase shadowOpacity:

```
    mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    mainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    mainView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    mainView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    mainView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    mainView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this simple extension

```
extension UIView {
        func addShadow() {
            self.layer.masksToBounds = false
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 2)
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add background color for the view.

```
mainView.backgroundColor = .white
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
mainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
mainView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
mainView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
mainView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Hope it helps