# How to add shadow to sections in TableView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

**[Please refer this screenshot for the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBflt.png)**

```
  //Top Left Right Corners
    var maskPathTop = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(cell.Bounds, UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.TopRight, new CoreGraphics.CGSize(8, 8));
    var shapeLayerTop = new CAShapeLayer();
    shapeLayerTop.Frame = cell.Bounds;
            shapeLayerTop.Path = maskPathTop.CGPath;

            //Bottom Left Right Corners
            var maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(cell.Bounds, UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight, new CoreGraphics.CGSize(8, 8));
    var shapeLayerBottom = new CAShapeLayer();
    shapeLayerBottom.Frame = cell.Bounds;
            shapeLayerBottom.Path = maskPathBottom.CGPath;

            //All Corners
            var maskPathAll = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(cell.Bounds, UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight | UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.TopRight, new CoreGraphics.CGSize(8, 8));
    var shapeLayerAll = new CAShapeLayer();
    shapeLayerAll.Frame = cell.Bounds;
            shapeLayerAll.Path = maskPathAll.CGPath;

            if (indexPath.Row == 0 && indexPath.Row == tableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.Section) - 1)
            {
                cell.Layer.Mask = shapeLayerAll;
            }
            else if (indexPath.Row == 0)
            {
                cell.Layer.Mask = shapeLayerTop;

            }

            else if (indexPath.Row == tableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.Section) - 1)
            {
                cell.Layer.Mask = shapeLayerBottom;
            }
```

I've tried this for getting Rounded corners for each section but in this I wasn't able to add shadows to each section . Can anyone suggest in C# since I am beginner to Xamarin iOS.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `shadowView` and `shadowView.AddSubview(cell);`, here is the code example:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UILabel cell = new UILabel();
    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
    cell.Text = "test";

    UIView shadowView = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100, 100, 200, 100));
    shadowView.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
    shadowView.Layer.ShadowRadius = 8.0f;
    shadowView.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(13.0, 13.0);
    shadowView.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.5f;

    cell.Frame = shadowView.Bounds;

    //Top Left Right Corners
    var maskPathTop = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(cell.Bounds, UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.TopRight, new CoreGraphics.CGSize(8, 8));
    var shapeLayerTop = new CAShapeLayer();
    shapeLayerTop.Frame = cell.Bounds;
    //shapeLayerTop.BorderWidth = 3;
    //shapeLayerTop.BorderColor = VM.RedColor.ToNativeColor().CGColor;
    shapeLayerTop.Path = maskPathTop.CGPath;

    //Bottom Left Right Corners
    var maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(cell.Bounds, UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight, new CoreGraphics.CGSize(8, 8));
    var shapeLayerBottom = new CAShapeLayer();
    shapeLayerBottom.Frame = cell.Bounds;
    //shapeLayerBottom.BorderColor = VM.RedColor.ToNativeColor().CGColor;
    //shapeLayerBottom.BorderWidth = 3;
    shapeLayerBottom.Path = maskPathBottom.CGPath;

    //All Corners
    var maskPathAll = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(cell.Bounds, UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight | UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.TopRight, new CoreGraphics.CGSize(8, 8));
    var shapeLayerAll = new CAShapeLayer();
    shapeLayerAll.Frame = cell.Bounds;
    //shapeLayerAll.BorderWidth = 3;
    //shapeLayerAll.BorderColor = VM.RedColor.ToNativeColor().CGColor;
    shapeLayerAll.Path = maskPathAll.CGPath;

    cell.Layer.Mask = shapeLayerAll;

    shadowView.AddSubview(cell);
    View.Add(shadowView);

}
```

Refer: [UIView with rounded corners and drop shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6949257/10539446)

Comment: Thanks! but this doesn't give shadow around sections in my tableView. Please refer the screenshot which I posted for more info.@Jack Hua - MSFT

Comment: I uploaded my test sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/iOS-Shadow) and please follow my code.

Comment: Hi , please see this screenshot of my requirement     [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptLr8.png]                                                                                           
what u suggested works fine for UIView but it doesn't work for shadows for separate **SECTIONS**  in a ** TABLEVIEW**.   @Jack Hua - MSFT

Comment: You SECTIONS actually is a View. So put the View(Cell) with shadows into your sections and you will get it.

Comment: Thanks :) but I am getting shadow for all the sides of the cell with u r implementation which does not satisfy my requirement. Please refer the screenshot attached  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptLr8.png])
 @Jack Hua- MSFT

Comment: Can you please share me a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: It will be more helpful if you could show using a TableView in your sample project. Thanks in Advance!  @Jack Hua MSFT

Comment: Hi what u implemented is working fine for UIView only but it looks crooked and weird for separate TableView sections.Please refer the screenshot. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvsUu.png] when there are two sections in the TableView and each section has one cell in it the shadow is going towards bottom and spikes are shown at the top . It is looking more weird when there are different number of cells in each sections. @Jack Hua MSFT

Comment: I wrote a new [sample](https://github.com/XfHua/iOS-TableView-Section-Shadow) and please check. If you need more cells in the section, you should just make sure the first cell and last cell in the section has the right corner:).

Comment: @Infinite Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).