# Swift Circle Image using image picker controller

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller, rounded-corners

I'm making an app that needs to access users image gallery and when he chooses an image for his profile image should become rounded. 
Here is the screenshot of the problem:
[image]

and a sample code used in the project

```
@objc func makeImageRounded(image: UIImageView){
        image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2
        image.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

this function is called in

```
   imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
            self.perform(#selector(makeImageRounded(image:)), with: profilePicture, afterDelay: 0)

    }
```

Comment: What is the content mode of UIImageView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Corner Radius on UIImageView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314640/setting-corner-radius-on-uiimageview-not-working)

Comment: Content mode is Aspect Fit

Comment: @DusanDimic set to aspect fill or scale to fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageView` should have Equal widths and heights [200*200 / 100*100]

Set `ImageView` contenMode, ScaleToFill / AspectFill / AspectFit

```
image.backGroundcolor = UIColor.red // To check imageView is in Circular or not
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2 // To get Rounded Corner

image.clipsToBounds = true // To Trim Outer frame
```

Comment: Using backgroundcolor showed me that my content mode was bad i changed content mode to Aspect Fill and that managed to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try , with imageView aspect ratio = 1

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2
    image.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

and call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: I tried it and the result is the same didn't fix it

Comment: that is the aspect ratio

Answer (score 1):

Your imageView is not rounded ?

try

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2
image.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

if it is still not working it is issue of content mode. you can check same with setting background colour of your imageView

if you set your content mode to aspectFill or scaleToFill then you can see image will be filled to bounds of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height / 2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```